# Максимальное значение матрицы через цикл

Tags: java

Как вывести максимальное значение матрицы через цикл. Я знаю, такой вопрос уже задавался, но я не понимаю того, что там написано.

---

Мой код:

```js
package com.company;

import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int[][] mas = new int [5][5];
            Random rn = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                    mas[i][j] = rn.nextInt(15);
                }
            }
                for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(mas[i][j] + "   ");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            int max = -1;


    }
}
```

---

Мне нужно, чтобы в переменную max было записано наибольшее значение из матрицы mas[i][j] с помощью цикла. Если можно, пожалуйста без Math.

Comment: Вы сделали два цикла, пробегающих по всей матрице. Если Вы знаете, как определить собственно максимум, что Вам мешает сделать еще один цикл для его поиска? Или использовать для этого, например, второй из имеющихся циклов?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужно лепить столько циклов.
Вы уже для этого сделали все, а значит, нужно просто записывать предыдущее большее число и сверять с новым и все.

```
int[][] mas = new int[5][5];
Random rn = new Random();
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
        int m = mas[i][j] = rn.nextInt(15);
        if (max < m) {
            max = m;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(max);
```

Answer (score -1):

Стандартный поиск максимума: пробегаем по массиву, сравниваем с переменной max если больше то заменяем

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] mas = new int [5][5];
        Random rn = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                mas[i][j] = rn.nextInt(15);
            }
        }
            for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(mas[i][j] + "   ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            int max = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mas.length; j++) {
                    if(mas[i][j] > max)
                        max = mas[i][j];
                }
            }

         System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```